# Nhibernate sort by datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

I'm trying to sort by datetime2(7) using CreateCriteria:

```
        var projection = Projections.Property("date"); 
        return session
            .CreateCriteria<KnihovnaNovinky>()
            .Add(Restrictions.Like("Type", type)) 
            .SetProjection(projection)
            .AddOrder(Order.Desc("Date"))
            .List<KnihovnaNovinky>();
```

Yet returned order is wrong. Could anyone help me? I'd like to keep criteria approach. Tried both Order.Asc / Desc, no effect.

Comment: In section 15.7 of the docs (http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/querycriteria.html) they set the projection directly after creating the criteria and before they add any restrictions or ordering. I have no experience with NHiberate but that might fix it?

Comment: That didn't work for me. Guess I am doing something else wrong.

Comment: I know that you said you wanted to keep the criteria approach but it would be useful to know if a `QueryOver` approach using `OrderBy` (http://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/queryqueryover.html)  behaves as expected. That would help to narrow down where the problem lays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed out "dumb" solution. As I wasn't able to order it in query I did it afterwards:

```
        List<KnihovnaNovinky> list = new KnihovnaNovinkyDao().GetAll() as List<KnihovnaNovinky>;
        list.Sort((ps1, ps2) => DateTime.Compare(ps1.Date, ps2.Date));
        list.Reverse();
        // works neat
```